# How do I grab the last X lines of a right triangle created using recursion?

Tags: python

So I am trying to create two functions (the use of additional functions is allowed). One that creates an entire right triangle by calling a recursive function, and then the recursive function itself is suppose to be able to grab the last X amount of lines of the complete right triangle and display them. The only thing is, the first function (triangle()) cannot be changed.

Here are the two functions (at least this is what I have so far for the recursive function):

```
def triangle(n):
    return recursive_triangle(n, n)


def recursive_triangle(k, n):
    if k > 0:
        print(k*'*')
        recursive_triangle(k-1, n)
```

So for example, when working properly:

```
triangle(6)
```

would give

```
******
 *****
  ****
   ***
    **
     *
```

and

```
recursive_triangle(3,6)
```

would give me the last 3 lines of a right triangle of base and height 6 (above triangle) like so:

```
***
 **
  *
```

I'm not sure how to use the relationship between n and k in a recursive method to implement the proper spacing required.

Comment: can you use two calls of recursive_triangle(), where it only takes 1 parameter? `recursive_triangle(3)` and `recursive_triangle(6)`. The last x lines of a any triangle is just a triangle with x height

Comment: Wouldn't it just be the same as calling `triangle(3)`? If that's the case, all you need is to subtract `k` from `n` to get the final length of the triangle. Now, it's a whole different issue on how you print it and why would you want to use recursion in the first place?

Comment: @zwer Wouldn't what be the same as calling triangle(3)? Also, using recursion here since I was told to use recursion as part of the question.

Comment: @MJames28 - `recursive_triangle(3, 6)` should show exactly what `trangle(3)` should show, right?

Comment: @zwer That's right! So you're suggesting I should subtract k from n where exactly?

Comment: `recursive_triangle(3, 6)` should not show the same thing as  `trangle(3)` because the first would have more starting spaces on each line. The op example missed this.. But the trick is the same you have to subtract k from n to find out the number of spaces to display before the stars

Comment: look at the format mini language.  `'{:>{}}'.format(hello, 10)` will create `'     hello'`. it right justifies the string to a width of ten.  That will help you with this.  and @KGS is correct.  recursive_triangle(3, 6) should print the bottom 3 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, `triangle(6)` should show a 6-lines tall triangle. This, I presume, also means that `triangle(3)` should show a 3-lines tall triangle, just as you presented in your example so there is no need to change anything (in the setup), you just need to write the `recursive_triangle()` function properly to subtract `k` from `n` before sending it to another function to do the actual printing.

However, what I think you want is to still consider the 'whole' triangle, but just not print the higher lines, i.e. instead of:

```
***
 **
  *
```

you want:

```
   ***
    **
     *
```

Notice the extra indentation as if the 'triangle' was printed but was missing the first 3 lines. In that case, you can use [`str.rjust()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) to do the justification for you, e.g.:

```
def recursive_triangle(k, n):
    if k > 0:
        print(("*" * k).rjust(n))
        recursive_triangle(k-1, n)
```

Now if you call `recursive_triangle(3, 6)` you'll get exactly what you're after (and it will also properly print deferred calls from `triangle()`).

**UPDATE**: If you want to return a string instead of printing, store the results in a `list` and then concatenate with new lines, i.e.:

```
def recursive_triangle_builder(k, n):
    result = []
    if k > 0:
        result.append(("*" * k).rjust(n))
        result += recursive_triangle_builder(k-1, n)
    return result

def recursive_triangle(k, n):
    return "\n".join(recursive_triangle_builder(k, n))

print(recursive_triangle(3, 6))  # or store the result instead of printing
```

Comment: Say I wanted to return the desired result rather than print, how would I go about doing this? Since if you replace print with return, recursive_triangle() isn't called since the function is left after the return statement. So for example it would be something like '****\n ***\n  **\n   *\n' when returned and if I printed the function call it would show the triangle.

Comment: I believe the question wants it so that when, for example, triangle(4) is called, what is obtained is ''****\n ***\n  **\n   *\n'' and when print(triangle(4)) is called, it shows the actual triangle. Would this change the design of the function though? I appreciate the explanations.

Comment: @MJames28 - Then create a separate function to build the triangle lines and defer the call to `recursive_triangle()` to it. Check the update again.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

```
print( (n-k) * ' ' + k * "*")
```

Comment: I know. This site misprinted my copy paste and now won't let me edit. It should be print( (n-k) * ' ' + k * "*")